# Black columns in corr plot

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, correlation

What does it mean when a column's color is black in a corr matrix plot?

Notebook snippet: https://gist.github.com/gumdropsteve/b483a739659e62009317df69bdc5de4a

[image: pd.DataFrame().corr(), cmap='coolwarm']

Comment: I guess it's because empty values: nan in column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your entire columns are converted to black because of presence of at least one NaN value.
To avoid this issue, you can use seaborn heatmap for plotting which only displays NaN cells as white without affecting the color of the entire column -

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(df.corr(),cmap='coolwarm')
```